# What is the correct way to possessivize (if that's a word) a compound noun?

Tags: possessives, compound-possessives

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Preferred way to apostrophise in case of dual or multiple ownership by distinct entities](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/37442/preferred-way-to-apostrophise-in-case-of-dual-or-multiple-ownership-by-distinct)

When forming the possessive of a compound noun, does one add "'s" to both or just one of the nouns?

For example,

> Jim's and Huck's raft

or

> Jim and Huck's raft

Comment: Some related questions: [this one](http://english.stackexchange.com/q/4226/11762) and [this one](http://english.stackexchange.com/q/57142/11762)

Comment: @FumbleFingers You are correct. I was sure there was one around here somewhere, but I didn't notice it in the first few search results.

Comment: @Jim: It took me a while! Next time it'll be easier even if we forget the best search terms, because if we don't find that original, we'll find *this* one - which will be closed with a link to the original!

Comment: @FumbleFingers Although I agree that this seems a duplicate, there is a deeper question that to my knowledge is unanswered. See my comment below.

Comment: @tchrist: Both the answers to the original question address the issue of *two different "possessions"* as well as two different "owners".

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The latter is correct:

> Jim and Huck's raft.

Comment: This is actually the same as how people say: “The person in the car’s phone rang”, in which you apply the *’s* to the end of the NP. It’s really quite interesting IMHO. “Jim and Huck” is one NP, and the *’s* gets applied to the end of the whole thing, just like with “person in the car”. See?

Comment: @tchrist: Sorry, I didn't understand your explanation. The sentence "The person in the car's phone rang." is not English.

Comment: Of course it’s English. You hear it all the time from native speakers.

Comment: @tchrist: I'm a native English speaker and have never seen that usage (I also Googled it and didn't get any hits). However, English is a big language so I could be wrong! Also, native speakers make mistakes all the time when speaking, so that might be the case.

Comment: Complex NPs like *chairman pro tem, surgeon general,* and *mother-in-law* all form a possessive by adding *’s* on the last word, no matter that that word is not the head noun of the NP. They form plurals in a very different way. **That type of *’s* is more than merely somewhat odd.** You also have an odd case with a double substantive in the NP when the second part is a pronoun: notice how the possessive of “It belongs to Bill and me, so it’s Bill’s and mine” not “so it’s Bill and mine”. There’s more afoot here than just putting *’s* at the end.

Comment: @tchrist: Yes, there are many odd things about possessives. Here is another one `New York’s and Chicago’s transportation systems`. <-- In this example having two `s is correct because "transportation systems" are two different entities. Unless you already have, buy a copy of "The Chicago Manual of Style" for more reference.