# A friend of Jane and Tom or A friend of Jane and Tom's?

Tags: possessives, double-possessive, compound-possessives

We can say:

She's a friend of mine.

She's a friend of Tom's.

She's a friend of my parents'.

But today I saw this: She's a friend of Jane and Tom.

Is it correct? Or should it be: She's a friend of Jane and Tom's?

Comment: Related and possible duplicate: [Why is it usually “friend of his”, but no possessive apostrophe with “friend of Peter”?](http://english.stackexchange.com/questions/50588/) ◊ ["Jim's and Huck's raft" vs "Jim and Huck's raft"](http://english.stackexchange.com/questions/60441/) ◊ [Preferred way to apostrophise in case of dual or multiple ownership by distinct entities](http://english.stackexchange.com/questions/37442/) ◊ and the many questions linked from those.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The grammatical form of the sentence you indicate is certainly

> She is a friend of Jane and Tom's.

meaning that they both know her and are her friends. However, particularly when speaking, the final ***"s"*** happens to be overlooked.

With reference to Jay's answer, the option ***She's a friend of Jane's and Tom's*** indicates that they are both friends to this girl/woman, but they do not necessarily know each other.

Answer (score 2):

"She's a friend of Jane and Tom" is correct. The "of" applies to "Jane and Tom" as a compound.

You could also say, "She's Jane's and Tom's friend."

People sometimes say, "She's a friend of Jane's and Tom's." But this is redundant: The "of" already indicates possession; you don't need to also use the "'s".

Comment: But you *do* say "a friend of mine" instead of "a friend of me". That is what makes English fun.

Comment: What about the last one: **She's a friend of Jane and Tom's**?

Comment: @rudra Sorry, what I was trying to say was: No. That's not only redundant but also inconsistent. Say either, "She's a friend of Jane and Tom", or "She's Jane's and Tom's friend". Don't mix the "of" and the "'s".

Comment: @JeffSahol Interesting point. Note that "mine" and "yours" are special cases. The normal possessive of "me" is "my". You can say, "She's my friend", but you wouldn't say, "She's a friend of my".