# How to write the "plural of plural"?

Tags: grammaticality, grammatical-number, possessives

I'm always confused how to write a "something of something else" in English, especially when plural is involved. For example, what would be the correct way to write the following sentences in English:

There are three phones, each phone is of a different type:

- Three types of phones?
- Three phone types?
- Three types of phone?

Similarly, there are several doctors, and each doctor has a car:

- The doctors' cars?
- The cars of the doctors?

Comment: Laurent - the second part of your question doesn't seem related to the first. Also it's been answered elsewhere on this site. e.g [What possessive forms are used for mutual 1st person ownership?](http://english.stackexchange.com/questions/8520/what-possessive-forms-are-used-for-mutual-1st-person-ownership), and [Plural possessive with separate posessions](http://english.stackexchange.com/questions/57142/plural-possessive-with-separate-posessions)

Comment: Isn't this general reference as well? http://www.kentlaw.edu/academics/lrw/grinker/LwtaPossessives.htm

Answer (score 14, accepted):

"Three types of phone" ("Three phone types" is also grammatically correct, but less usual).

"The doctors' cars" ("The cars of the doctors" is also grammatically correct, but clumsy).

Comment: What about "job's descriptions" vs "jobs description"? The full sentence: "I recommend you to read ... .... to get ideas..."

Comment: If there's only one job, I would use "the job description". If there's more than one job and/or description, "the job descriptions". In these cases, "job" is used to qualify "description(s)", not as a single or plural noun in its own right. Some may prefer to hyphenate as "job-description(s)". If you want to use a phrase like the ones in the original post, "description(s) of the job(s)" would be less clumsy than "the job's (jobs') description(s)".

Comment: Thank you! Now I can re-phrase my questions better. What about (1) many jobs, each job has only **one** description. (2) many jobs, each job has **some** requirements.

Comment: @Mosh Feu As I wrote above: "the job descriptions/requirements" ("job" in an adjectival role) or "the descriptions of/requirements for the jobs" (make it clear in the rest of your document which descriptions/requirements are relevant to which jobs).